# Update with new records while Pagination in Firebase, iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a `posts` table in `Firebase` database with the following structure:

```
"posts": {
         "111" : {
           "pName" : "ABC",
           "pMessage" : "Hello",
           "pOrder" : 555
         },
         "112" : {
           "pName" : "BCD",
           "pMessage" : "ELLO",
           "pOrder" : 444
         },
         "113" : {
           "pName" : "A",
           "pMessage" : "Ollo",
           "pOrder" : 555
         }.
         .....
       }
```

There a quite a few records in the `posts` table. So, I have implemented pagination to fetch 20 records at a time from `Firebase`. I have set `observeEventType` as `FIRDataEventType.Value`, so that it will listen to all activity in `posts`. Here is the code for pagination:

```
/*
    retrieve current set of posts sorted by pOrder of posts
    */
   func retrievePost(offset: NSNumber, completion: (result: AnyObject?, error: NSError?)->()){
       // As this method is called from viewDidLoad and fetches 20 records at first.
       // Later when user scrolls down to bottom, its called again
       let postsRef = ref.child(kDBPostRef)
       var startingValue:AnyObject?
       // starting  value will be nil when this method is called from viewDidLoad as the offset is not set
       if offset == 0{
           startingValue = nil
       }
       else{
           startingValue = offset
       }
       // sort records by pOrder fetch offset+1 records
       self.refHandler = postsRef.queryOrderedByChild("pOrder").queryStartingAtValue(startingValue).queryLimitedToFirst(kPostLimit + 1).observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
           // flag is for setting the last record/ 21st as offset
           var flag = 0
           var tempPost:[Post] = []
               // iterate over children and add to tempPost
               for item in snapshot.children {
                   // check for offet, the last row(21st) is offset ; Do not add last element in the main table list
                   flag += 1
                   if flag == 21 {
                       // this row is offset
                       self.kOffsetKey = item.value?["pOrder"] as! NSNumber
                       continue
                   }
                   // create Post object
                   let post = Post(snapshot: item as! FIRDataSnapshot)
                   // append to tempPost
                   tempPost.append(post)
               }
               // return to the closure
               completion(result:tempPost, error:nil)
       })
   }
```

Here I am setting the `offset` each time this method is called to fetch next 20 records.

Now, Suppose I updated a post(by updating `pMessage`) and for that update the reference handler is calling this particular method(`retrievePost`) again. To synchronize the data, I am maintaining  an `offsetDict` dictionary which will keep record of offset for a particular range of data:

```
   offsetDict:[Range(0-20): "nil", Range(21-40):"444", Range(41-60):"666"]
```

Therefore when `retrievePost` is called by an update activity, the offset will be chosen from this dictionary otherwise the offset will be as set by normal retrieve activity (`self.kOffsetKey`). 
So my query is:

1. Is this the right approach to achieve this particular functionality?
2. Now, suppose I add more new records to posts by a back end service, in that case, how will my `refHandler` handle fetching new records and display it automatically to app without any `pull request` kind of thing?